# Do the posterior legs of mosquito plays the role of antenna?

Tags: entomology, physiology, ethology

I have had this question for years and this stems from the observation that when I bring my hand close to a mosquito lying on some surface (e.g : wall) I see its posterior legs - which are in a strange posture then (going upwards - moving slightly toward my hand...

I wonder whether these legs have another role than standing ? Correct me if I'm wrong but in my humble knowledge some arachnids have the front pair of legs endowed with sensory function ,so is it a similar case with mosquitoes ?